# WebView history not working on Android 7.0 and 8.0

Tags: android, android-webview

`webView` history does not work properly. When you use `webView.goBack()` to navigate back to the page visited before, sometimes this page is skipped and the `webView` goes back to the first visited webpage.

Other times the history is simply empty resulting in `webView.canGoBack()` returning false, although you had visited a page just before.

Comment: Post the code you were trying